# Android OS on VirtualBox very slow mouse

Tags: mouse, virtualbox

I am running Android x86 on Virtual Box 5.2.0.
After disabling mouse integration and setting up Pointing Device to PS/2 Mouse, I have a mouse when I start Android OS but it is so slow that it is impossible to click on any icon.
Is there any solution?

Thanks, T

Comment: And your pc is?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.12.6

Comment: Hardware, mate. I tought maybe it was throttling because of low end hardware

Comment: I have tried it on two different Mac computers and I have the same problem. Maybe it is my iso file. I guess I will try different source.

Comment: Maybe it's ISO and maybe it's some kind of incompatibility with mac, just guessing..

Comment: It is definitely not iso and I also tried Android 6 (still the same problem). Also I tried this on two different MACs.

Comment: I have a slow mouse, on the installed version (not virtualized).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue from Android x86 6 upper version in VBox. It runs in a MacBook Pro Late 2013 with 16GB RAM. I tried to set different size of CPU/RAM/VideoRAM but no help.

When I installed it in VMWare, there is no such issue. So it looks related to VBox.

Comment: VMware supports up to 2GB virtual video memory and VirtualBox supports a maximum of 256MB. That's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

*I am not Sure if this Was the Factor of the problem but worth giving it a shot*

**On the Android VM**

1. Go to settings
2. Select the "Language & Keyboard" option towards the bottom of the screen.
3. Select "Pointer speed" under the "Mouse/trackpad" heading.
4. Set the speed

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. In my case it did not help. Someone responded to me that "slow mouse" on VirtualBox and Android OS is a normal behavior. Since I needed it to work I tried another software from VMWare and it worked much better.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have an android VM working on my mac using VMWare Fusion and the androidx86 images for VMware on this site: https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/

For whatever reason I wasn't able to do a successful self install using the androidx86 isos on VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the video memory to 256MB by command line and it should help the speed and accuracy of the mouse in your Android VM.

Here is the command:

```
username$ vboxmanage modifyvm "Androidv9" --vram 256
```

Here is a video that will help: [Virtualbox 6 Performance Trick to Get More Video Memory](https://youtu.be/EcceeuZYURs)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have a usable mouse for android-x86 on VBox by using 128MB display memory (maximum in my case) and VBoxVGA (instead of VBoxSVGA)